# "File is not a database" error backed up sqlite database

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have  a file "database.sqlite" that is a database backup from a program I use on my computer to collect sensor data (Hamilton ArcAir is the name of the program if that helps). When I try opening the database in the sqlite chrome extension, DB Browser, and PHP I get an error saying that the file is not a database. Does anyone have an idea about what is going on here?

If I create a database with DB browser, insert a table, and add some rows of data, all of the programs can open and work on that file just fine. Then, when I tell ArcAir to backup the database or create a new one - that database is not recognized anywhere.

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Thanks

Comment: Is it an actual copy of the database, or just a dump of the create and insert statements needed to recreate the database?

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I believe it is a backup of the database itself, since upon restore the program would restore the saved sensor data. Is there a way to check this? The program itself doesn't have a ton of documentation other than a statement in a manual stating: "The database is secured and can be accessed only through ArcAir software"

Comment: That sounds like it might use one of the encryption extensions and not a standard sqlite version.

Comment: Open file e.g. notepad is first 16 characters like `SQLite format 3`? if not then not a database and needs to be handled restored by ArcAir.

Comment: When I open with notepad the file is filled with a bunch of foreign characters and no english text. Shawn - if that is the case will there be any way to open the file outside of the program? I have a config file from the program with a number of "publickeytoken" values stored in it... Not sure what those are used for though!

Comment: Then you need outside program that can open using ArcAir, DBBrowser is limited what it can open encrypted see [How to open a database that is protected by a password?](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/155).